# How to improve the performance of subwoofer made with a TDA2030?

Tags: audio, filter, performance

I have built a subwoofer amplifier with the IC TDA2030, it works well with my 8Ohm 30W woofer.

[image: Circuit diagram]

How can I increase the bass? It is not much as expected, is it possible to improve the bass by altering the circuit or do I have to design a bass filter for this?

I have seen the [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/25043/STMICROELECTRONICS/TDA2030/+Q41WWUORlHDyRHOIpa/1XXyxeogyRIHLI+/datasheet.pdf?p1=STMICROELECTRONICS&p2=TDA2030&x=292&y=48) and tried to do it myself, but I don't know how to change the filter configuration in this circuit.

Comment: Where's this circuit from? What's D1 doing there? What's VCC? What's the speaker impedance?

Comment: It is a feeble amplifier if booming bass is important to you. If you add a bass-boost filter to this amp, you risk clipping distortion. Perhaps a better speaker would please you more: for example, one with a tuned port.

Comment: @pipe https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/subwoofer-amplifier-circuit-using-tda2030 this is the circuit I'm following, but the capacitor polarity is marked incorrectly in this circuit, that's why I didn't attached this circuit. In the current circuit they are well placed.

Comment: If it's providing the maximum power on the voltage you did not specify and signal you did not specify ….then you can't improve it. You either need a bass boost filter or a larger amp to increase the base. The intent of the amp shown in the link is to boost the base for a phone …...what are you using it for?

Comment: It is far better to eliminate C2 and use two AMPs in differential out mode to get 3x the output power and response to 0Vdc out.